# arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF causing symbols to separate from outlines?

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, export, pdf, arcgis-10.7

I have a python script that runs through various data layers and then exports a final map to a PDF stored locally. In each map there are up to four different symbols. When I print to PDF, I see all of the symbols that are a circle come through fine, but when I print maps that contain triangle shaped symbols, the outline for the triangle is skewed from the symbol fill.  If I manually print to PDF from within ArcMap, this is a non-issue, this is only happening when I load my script and call the arcpy.mapping.ExportToPDF from within it.

[image]

I have already checked to see if the outline X/Y positions were off, but they're not, they're both set to 0.

I don't understand what's happening to the triangles that's not happening to the circle symbols in my maps. A comparison of the symbol properties between the two do not reveal anything obvious.

If I need to do this via python, is there anything I need to consider to prevent this issue, any options I need to use?

Comment: Can you post your code?  Have you tried setting the convert markers and embed fonts arguments to true in your script?  See this link:  https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/analyze/arcpy-mapping/exporttopdf.htm